# windows php curl install : recommend a good site?

Tags: php, windows-xp, installation, curl

So I'm struggling to get php curl installed on my windows xp professional machine and I've probably tried 5 different sites which either dont' work or refers to missing file references like the ca certificates and such.

I'm looking to write a php script which logs into a site ssl, captures the page data using regex and emailing it to me.  Before I can get there, I need ssl curl.  I was wondering if someone can recommend a better site or tutorial which effectively walks me through that step by step.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To enable curl with php you have to follow these steps:

1. **Find used php.ini file.** You should just put in script (contents : <?php phpinfo(); ?>) in your inetpub, call it from browser and search for php.ini.
2. **Uncomment extension=php_curl.dll**. You can do this by removing ; in front of line.
3. Check that **php_curl.dll exists in extension_dir** . If it does not exist - download Win32 zip package of corresponding php version from http://php.net/downloads.php .
4. **Check that libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll are found within path.** You can get them by installing OpenSSL http://www.openssl.org/

Comment: i have php installed through IIS7 web platform installer.. im not sure where PATH is supposed to be.. but i find libeay32 and ssleay32.dll in C:\program files\PHP\v5.3  and all of the following are done and restarted.. but yet it cURL doesn't work.

Comment: ^ refer: http://serverfault.com/questions/286499/how-to-install-curl-with-ssl-to-php-5-on-iis7

Answer (score 0):

I found the same thread on stack overflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181082/how-do-i-install-curl-on-windows

however it focuses on apache running on windows.  I need an install which works with IIS and PHP5

Comment: you can edit your post. no need to add another answer :>